# Suddenly can not move bones after making some shape key

Tags: animation, rigging, shape-keys

Yeah the headline says it all. I cant find the solution myself :(
I made some shape key for the hand and couldnt move finger bones after that. The hip bones couldnt move too.

Here's blend file
http://www.mediafire.com/file/19qp6k39f10dx68/Judy.blend

Answer (score 0):

I can't open your blend in my release, but if you created the shape by applying the armature as a shape key, then you just need to add another armature modifier to your mesh and select it in the resulting Object field. If that's the issue then don't forget to select all bones in pose mode and ALT+r then ALT+g to reset the pose to default.